# Detrrminant of a matrix

Tags: matrices

I need to prove that $\det A_n \ne 0$, if $a_i \ne a_j$ and $a_i \ne 0$, where
$A_n$ is a matrix with the first row 
$a_1 +a_2, a_2+a_3,  \ldots , a_{n-1}+a_n , a_n$.
Second row consists of all products of two elemnts where at least one is $a_i$ or $a_{i+1}$ for $2i$ - entire. For example $a_{12} = \sum_{i \ne 1} a_1 a_i + \sum_{i \ne 2} a_2 a_i - a_1a_2$.
Third row consist of all products of three elements where at least one is $a_i$ or $a_{i+1}$ or $a_{i+2}$ for $3i$ - entire. For example $a_{13} = \sum_{i<j; i,j \ne 1} a_1 a_i a_j + \sum_{i<j; i,j \ne 2} a_2 a_i a_j - \sum_{i\ne 1,2} a_1a_2a_i$
and so on. Every entire of last row are $1$.

For example if $n=2$:
$
A_2=\begin{pmatrix}
a_1+a_2 & a_2 \\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
; \det A_2 = a_1$.

$n=3$: $A_3= \begin{pmatrix}
a_1+a_2 & a_2+a_3 & a_3 \\
a_1a_2+a_1a_3+a_2a_3 & a_1a_2+a_1a_3+a_2a_3 & a_1a_3+a_2a_3 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$; $\det A_3 = a_1a_2(a_1-a_3)$.

$n=4$: $A_4 = \begin{pmatrix}
a_1+a_2 & a_2+a_3 & a_3+ a_4 & a_4 \\
a_1a_2+a_1a_3+a_1a_4+a_2a_3+a_2a_4 & a_1a_2+a_1a_3+a_2a_3+a_2a_4+a_3a_4 & a_1a_3+a_1a_4+a_2a_3+a_2a_4+a_3a_4 & a_1a_4+a_2a_4+a_3a_4 \\
a_1a_2a_3 + a_1a_2a_4+a_1a_3a_4+a_2a_3a_4 & a_1a_2a_3 + a_1a_2a_4+a_1a_3a_4+a_2a_3a_4 & a_1a_2a_3 + a_1a_2a_4+a_1a_3a_4+a_2a_3a_4 & a_1a_2a_4+a_1a_3a_4+a_2a_3a_4 \\
1 & 1 & 1 &1
\end{pmatrix};$ 
$\det A_4= a_1a_2a_3(a_1 - a_3)(a_1-a_4)(a_2-a_4) $.

May be it is a well-known determinant?

Comment: Did you try to do some particular cases with $\;n=1,2,3\;$ ...? I didn't understand the definition of the matrix, btw.

Comment: Hm, I wrote cases $n=2,3,4$.